# Amazon MySQL RDS and Hibernalte

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I used to have a server with MySQL on it. I'm growing and just moved MySQL to Amazon rds. MY war file is using hibernate.. I CAN conntect with mySqlWorkBench to the cloud DB, NO Problems there, but once I upload my war file to tomcat and hit it with my API I get 500NullPioinnter exception...
It says

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

my hibernate file has this:

```
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">600</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">myPassword</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://mydb.cpenxxkl0fwa.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mydb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to restart your sql server?

Also keep in mind that your AMAZON SQL SERVER IS HOSTED ON LINUX environment and in MySQL All the table values are key sensitive! I would check on table names first. Good luck

Comment: Thank you! that is it. Key sensitive table names! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the firewall rules on Amazon RDS and EC2/Elasticbeanstalk environments through Security Groups.

The group of RDS must have an inbound rule with the EC2/EBS environments Security Group as source

I would recommend the use of the system property "JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING" to connect to your RDS instance instead of putting it directly on the persistence.xml but that is completely up to you.

Also, I think you can not connect as "root" user. You should also check your username/password settings there.

Comment: I CAN access my db from amazon vm with mysql console, so meaning my security groups are ok, my war file was doing something and wasnt failing on the connection.
 Gino got it just right, the ONLY problem i had was that the table tames were in small letters, but the Hibernate was looking for the camel latter tables. That is it.  I honestly had NO CLUE that in linux that would matter but in windows server it is ok, but that was my only problem. Thanks for the answer though, i really appreciate you trying! Keep it UP!!